# Filtering varargs of type Any

Tags: swift

I have the following class and constructor :

```
class List<T> {
    var value: T
    var next: List<T>?

init(_ items: Any...) {

}
```

The constructor can accept things like  :
`let list =   List<Any>(List<Int>(7, 2), 6, List<Any>(3, List<Int>(5, 1)))`

My goal in the constructor is to filter out the numbers 7,2,6,3,5,1 in that particular order, ofcourse they can be Strings since it is a template.What I have tried is

```
    init(_ items: Any...) {
        for info in items 
        {

           if let str = info as? T {
             if let str2 = info as? List<T> {

             }
             else
             {
                     print("this is primitive \(info)")
             }


           }
        }
```

however as I result I get :

```
this is primitive 7
this is primitive 2
this is primitive 5
this is primitive 1
this is primitive 3
this is primitive main.List<Swift.Int>
this is primitive main.List<Swift.Int>
this is primitive 6
```

so I don't seem to filter out the main.List and also not in order, any ideas how I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the order of handling the varargs doesn't seem to be sequential but rather like it is a recursive call to `init(_ items: Any...)`so I don't think you can get the order you want.

Regarding the print that main.list is a primitive comes from the call

```
init(3, List<Int>(5, 1)
```

where T is Any and 3 and the List object is each an instance of T. This becomes much clearer if you add a print as the first line of the `init`

```
print(items)
```

Below is my test version of the init

```
init(_ items: Any...) {
    print(items)
    for item in items {
        switch item {
        case is List<T>:
            print("Is list")
        case is T:
            print("Primitive \(item)")
        default:
            print("Other stuff")
        }
    }
}
```